# Can I upgrade the CPU and RAM in my Toshiba Satellite laptop?

Tags: laptop, memory, cpu, upgrade

I have a Toshiba Satellite C855D-S5303 laptop with the following specs:

- Processor: AMD E-300 APU with Radeon(tm)HD Graphics GHz
- RAM: 2.00 GB (1.59 GB usable)

I would like to upgrade the hardware but am not sure what the motherboard can handle. How can I determine what components I can upgrade and what are the best replacement components available for my laptop? I would like to achieve the best possible configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you can can upgrade on that laptop is the memory - which can go up to 16GB.

Comment: Why not the CPU? Please Explain!

Comment: On laptops, CPUs are soldered onto the motherboard.  They can not be upgraded

Comment: What would be the disk size I can upgrade to?

Comment: You can buy any Hard drive available as long as its a 2.5 inch SATA drive - all modern consumer laptop drives are

Comment: @Bryan: An SSD provides a nice boost to any ageing PC.

Comment: @Keltari currently 2GB DDR3 1066MHz memory ram is installed, do you know if this can be upgraded to 2(4GB DDR# 1333MHz)? Or what is the max memory speed for this laptop?

Comment: go to http://crucial.com and use their memory advisor.  It will tell you everything you need to know.

Comment: While it's true that the CPU in this particular laptop cannot be upgraded, to imply that that's the case for all laptops is incorrect. Plenty of laptops still have socketed CPUs that can be swapped out.

Comment: @Bryan DDR3-1333 RAM should work fine in your laptop, but most likely it will downclock to 1066 MHz.

Answer (score -1):

I think you cannot find any laptop CPU in retail stores, all upgrade in laptop world is limited to ram and hard disk, but if you can find "**AMD Dual-Core A6-4400M**" that equip-ted with **AMD Radeon™ HD 7520G** you can upgrade to it without any issue.
I'm not sure about memory support of you notebook but I think it's limited to Max 4GB, also using SSD hard disk may boost your performance.

Comment: What would be the disk size I can upgrade to?

Comment: There is no limit, It's only to your budget but of you are looking for fast hard disk (7200 RPM) it's Limited to Max 750GB and for normal Hard disk (5400 RPM) It's limited to Max 2TB. for SSD it's Limited to 128GB or 256GB

Comment: So much misinformation here. Laptop upgrades are **not** limited to the RAM and hard disk (though ironically this particular one is); eBay and Amazon are just two places that sell laptop CPUs. RAM on this laptop is limited to 16 GB, per [official specs](http://cdgenp01.csd.toshiba.com/content/product/pdf_files/detailed_specs/satellite_C855D-S5303.pdf). Finally, several manufacturers make 500+ GB SSDs, and at least one makes a 1 TB 7200 rpm hard drive.